# Unable to move file with MS Graph API for Onedrive. 200 Response containing old Parent ID

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

So I'm quite a fan of the Graph API to manage Onedrive from my server.
Now I'm trying to use the Graph API to move a file from one directory to another one following the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_move?view=odsp-graph-online).

Now in order to do so, I send (PATCH) the following to *https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/01A2ASUEXPG7EKMCTPDJDY7L5YMVTNWHMO*:

```
{'parentReference': {'id': '01A2ASUEVXTMODEW6HIJC3MSXT5JJ4JLRK'}}
```

And I receive:

```json
{
   "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('b9dc908f-6c6f-463b-a568-9361fabdc995')/drive/items/$entity",
   "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl":"xxxx",
   "createdDateTime":"2022-04-20T08:46:12Z",
   "eTag":"\"{A6C837EF-6F0A-471A-8FAF-B86566DB1D8E},1\"",
   "id":"01A2ASUEXPG7EKMCTPDJDY7L5YMVTNWHMO",
   "lastModifiedDateTime":"2022-04-20T08:46:12Z",
   "name":"IMG.png",
   "webUrl":"https://xxxx-my.sharepoint.com/personal/xxxx-uitzendbureau_nl/Documents/Loonstroken%20(alleen%20voor%20toevoegen)/xxxx/IMG.png",
   "cTag":"\"c:{A6C837EF-6F0A-471A-8FAF-B86566DB1D8E},1\"",
   "size":382692,
   "createdBy":{
      "user":{
         "email":"Online@xxxx.nl",
         "id":"b9dc908f-6c6f-463b-a568-9361fabdc995",
         "displayName":"Online beheer"
      }
   },
   "lastModifiedBy":{
      "user":{
         "email":"Online@xxxxx.nl",
         "id":"b9dc908f-6c6f-463b-a568-9361fabdc995",
         "displayName":"Online beheer"
      }
   },
   "parentReference":{
      "driveType":"business",
      "driveId":"b!u2WpOb6qnkS_6foMbPUq90TwxghBinBMhj9DwokQnQefs7rIOSQYS5kmJNV5uSJ7",
      "id":"01A2ASUEWGZQX5GCGE2RFL6J3WBIW2LTUC",
      "path":"/drive/root:/Loonstroken (alleen voor toevoegen)/xxxxxx"
   },
   "file":{
      "mimeType":"image/png",
      "hashes":{
         "quickXorHash":"Yk0eRqT2ThqJHamo0AMLstI0CBI="
      }
   },
   "fileSystemInfo":{
      "createdDateTime":"2022-04-20T08:46:12Z",
      "lastModifiedDateTime":"2022-04-20T08:46:12Z"
   },
   "image":{
      
   },
   "shared":{
      "scope":"users"
   }
}
```

As you can see:

```json
'parentReference': {'driveType': 'business', 'driveId': 'xxx', 'id': '01A2ASUEWGZQX5GCGE2RFL6J3WBIW2LTUC', 'path': '/drive/root:/Loonstroken (alleen voor toevoegen)/xxxxxx'}
```

The parentReference ID has not changed to the one provided in the request, but still a 200 is returned. Also the file obviously was not moved.

Any idea what might be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Seems this was an issue on Microsoft's end. I now get a correct parentReference in the response.